# PHP Apache Docker container: No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/xdebug" in some networks in Ubuntu 18

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu-18.04, xdebug, pecl

I`m installing xdebug with pecl in my php/apache docker container:

```
FROM php:apache-bullseye

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

This works in my WiFi. But when I plug in my cable, I get error:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/xdebug"
```

Any idea what could cause this? Could this be an Ubuntu problem? I`m using Ubuntu 18. The workaround to switch network is easy. But this can`t be a solution.

Comment: What's the diff between WiFi and cable? In particular, things like nameservers or e.g. caching proxies may make a difference. That said, I'd avoid PECL and use packaged extensions. For PHP, search for according backports of PHP which include XDebug.

Comment: Maybe that works with a more current version of your containers, like `php:apache-bookworm`? Also, as this looks like a networking problem, it could be off-topic here

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - How would you install xdebug with one of the official php images?

Comment: Bullseye is the name of a Debian release, so search for according backports.